# Do you know any Linux based CCTV solution?

Tags: linux, video

I'm looking for CCTV solution. I found this http://www.zoneminder.com/ but last version has been released about 2 years ago.

Comment: Look at http://superuser.com/questions/58765/timelapse-surveillance-with-webcam-what-software/58786#58786

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IP cams are quite cheap these days, it's dedicated hardware and there's the advantage of easy configurability. If there's functionality in those IP cams a GNU/Linux+webcam setup can't give you, and you don't mind shelling out for it, then by all means go that way.

Also updates for ZoneMinder might be on their way: [Forum Posts](http://www.zoneminder.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=16890)

Comment: I already have six working CCTV cams and looking only for new software solution(old windows app is terrible in use)

Comment: What windows app are you currently running?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [Motion](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/WebHome).

Answer (score 1):

I know people who've successfully used zoneminder and Cisco IP cameras (PVC2300 I think) for a Linux based CCTV system. But from memory there was a good about of work building a setup around both of these products to achieve exactly what was needed.

Answer (score 1):

We're running Zoneminder in production. As far as I'm aware there are no showstopper bugs on it, so I'm not too worried that it's out of active development; it's probably worth looking into, at least.

Answer (score 0):

While there are lots of hardware you can buy / attach (and I second Teddy's recommendation for motion) I have found [Axis](http://www.axis.com/) cameras (and their other hardware) to be very good quality / well documented / well supported / reliable etc....

> but last version has been released about 2 years ago.

You don't want to use stable software????

Comment: Just saw your comment elsewhere regarding existing CCTVs - analogue? - Linux provides a standard API - so any video4linux capture card (v4l) will work with the cameras and most software.